# Find the operator norm on $C([0,1])$ with $T(f(x))=xf(x)$

Tags: real-analysis

let  $T \in B(C([0,1])) $ defined by 
$$ \forall f  \in C([0,1]), (Tf)(x)=xf(x)$$
and consider that $B(C([0,1]))$ is equipped with the max-norm. Find operator norm $|T|$

---

Let $T:M_1 \to M_2$ a bounded linear operator  then

$$|| T|| \sup_{x \in M_1 ,x \neq 0 } \frac{||Tx||_{M_1}}{||x||_{M_1}}
=\sup_{x \in M_1 , || x||_{M_1}=1} ||Tx ||_{M_2} $$

---

$$ \begin{aligned}
||T||&= \sup_{f \in C([0,1])} \frac{||T f ||_\infty}{||f||_\infty}
   = \sup_{f \in C([0,1])} \frac{\max_{x \in [0,1]}|x f(x) ||}{\max_{x \in [0,1]}|f(x)|}
\\ &=\sup |x|=1 
\end{aligned}$$

not sure that canceling out $f(x)$ is allowed. OR if the propostion of the operator norm was used corectly

---

Was suppused to show that it is bounded operator. $x, f(x)$ are continous their preimage is closede so its image is closed and bounded and we have that

$$\begin{aligned}
||Tx  ||_\infty &= \max_{x \in [0,1]} |Tf(x)|=\max_{x \in [0,1]}|xf(x)|
\\ &\leq \max_{x \in [0,1]}|x| \max_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x)|
=1\max |f(x)|=||f||_\infty
\end{aligned} $$
So $||Tf||_\infty \leq ||f||_\infty$

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $x\in[0,1]$, you have 
$$
|xf(x)|\leq|f(x)|
$$
for all $x$, and so $\|Tf\|\leq\|f\|$. This shows that $T$ is bounded and that $\|T\|\leq1$. In your argument, you can directly say that $\max|xf(x)|\leq\max|f(x)$.

Now let $f\in C[0,1]$ be $f(x)=1$.  Then $$\|Tf\|=\max\{|x|:\ x\in[0,1]\}=1$$ and $\|f\|=1$, so $\|Tf\|=\|f\|$, which implies that $\|T\|\geq1$. It follows that $\|T\|=1$.

Comment: is there a reason you didn't take $f$ to be the constant function $1$?

Comment: That I didn't think much about it. Most of the time I think about problems of this kind I somehow need to patch a continuous function. But yes, in this case $f(x)=1$ is the obvious choice.

Comment: Thanks :)! I just wanted to make sure I wasn't being dopey.

Comment: Nope. That would have been me :)